# Why does position of x-template section matter for vue templates to work with data?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have an vue app and a global component. Both have a data property. For the component I use the x-template way to keep my html code together. I have encountered a strange error where the data was not available in the component, although the component was rendered properly when I didn't access the data in the component.

Here comes the HTML:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id='app'>
  <p>Here is the app: {{message}}</p>
  <my-component></my-component>

  <script type="text/x-template" id="template">
      <div>
          <p>This is the component: {{secondmsg}}</p>
      </div>
  </script>

</div>
```

Here comes the .ts-file:

```
Vue.component('my-component',
    {
        template: '#template',
        data: function () {
            return {
                secondmsg: 'Works again!'
            }
        }
    });
    
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: "App works!"        
    }
});
```

**This does not work**, it says

> secondmsg is not defined

However, it works if you

- don't access secondmsg. Then, the component renders right. Or:
- if you don't use the [x-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#X-Templates) version but rather use [inline-template](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Inline-Templates) for the component. Or:
- if you move the script section below the div closing the vue app

So after trying a lot, I found these workarounds, but I would really like to know why it matters where you define your x-template if you use the data (or the props) property. I didn't find any hint in the docs.

Note: I use Razor Pages with partial views, that's why in the standard case the x-template got rendered within the div.

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q8ho0o85/#fork) to play around if you don't believe me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is the following:

1. Vue tries to render `#app`
2. Vue gets the the template to render from html DOM
3. Vue sees that there is a `message` reference, this works
4. Vue sees that there is a component reference to `my-component`, it adds it to the render stack
5. Vue sees a reference to `secondmsg`, and then fails

If it didn't fail it would now continue with rendering `my-component`

As you already discovered, the following works for the problem:

> - don't access secondmsg. Then, the component renders right. Or:
> - if you don't use the x-template version but rather use inline-template for the component. Or:
> - if you move the script section below the div closing the vue app

Answer (score 2):

The parent Vue is being attached to `#app`, which includes the x-template. Attaching a Vue to an element tells Vue to use the contents of that element as a template to create the DOM. Since the x-template is in there, and it has an interpolation string in it, the parent Vue tries to do the interpolation, but `secondmsg` isn't defined in the parent.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate your help! The reason for me to mark @Ferrybig's answer was mostly that he has less reputation so far :-)