# Vue reference is not defined for variable inside component

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vue.js

I am trying to integrate vue.js with asp.net MVC. As the title says I have a problem with component variables.

I made a simplified code to show you guys what I am talking about.

This is my "about page", which contains some message and component:

```html
<h3>VueJS 2 in ASP.NET MVC 5</h3>
<div id="aboutPage">
    <el-row>
        <el-col>
            <p>
                {{ message }}
            </p>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
    <el-row>
        <el-col>
            <p>
                <smpl-component></smpl-component>
            </p>
        </el-col>
    </el-row>
</div>

<script src="~/Scripts/smpl-component.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="smpl-template">
    <p><button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
    <p>The button has been clicked {{ counter }} times</p>
</script>



<script>
    var aboutPage = new Vue({
        el: '#aboutPage',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue! in About Page'
        }
    });
</script>
```

The code inside `smpl-component.js` is simple:

```js
Vue.component('smpl-component', {
    template: '#smpl-template',
    data: {
        counter: 0,
    }
});
```

This is simple but it gives me Error:

> ReferenceError: counter is not defined.

The reason for the error is because in my `About.cshtml` file inside my `aboutPage` js I don't have a `counter` variable.

I'm struggling for the second day in trying to make this work.

The only way that it works is when I define component like this:

```js
Vue.component('smpl-component', {
    template: '<p><button v-on:click="counter += 1">Add One More Click</button></p>
    <p>The button has been clicked {{ counter }} times</p>',
    data: {
        counter: 0,
    }
});
```

But I don't like this way, because in my head project the component will contain much more code.

How can I make this work in any smart way?

Comment: The easiest solution would be to create a wrapper component that holds both your components. Then in the `smpl-component` you can send down prop `counter`, and emit umpdated value (more reading: https://medium.com/@sky790312/about-vue-2-parent-to-child-props-af3b5bb59829)

Comment: BTW does it make any difference if you move your `script` tag including your component after the `x-template` ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193378/why-does-position-of-x-template-section-matter-for-vue-templates-to-work-with-da

Comment: I used solution from thread that u linked :) thanks